# Check if li has ul

Tags: css, less

We have a subnavigation with several UL elements with li's with UL elements in it.

Consider the following:

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">link level 1</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">link level 2</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">link level 2</a>

                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#">link level 3</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

We need an arrow behind all of the anchor tags, except on level 3.

I now have the following CSS, but this only displays the arrow icon behind level 2.

```
ul {
    padding:20px 0 0 0;
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 13px;
        & > li {
            list-style-type: none;
            & > a:not(:last-child):after {
                margin-top:3px;
                content:"\E259";
                font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
                text-align:right;
                font-size: 10px;
                float:right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This draws the icon where a is not the last element. But we also need to have the arrow behind level 1, which according to this CSS is the last element, so the arrow icon is not drawn.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by that.

Comment: Please, post a demo which is shown your problem. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @alirezasafian Providing the code here is what is required. Please don't make users think that providing links to external services is required. You can copy and paste the code yourself. Even better, suggest that the user use the Stack Overflow -provided "snippets" feature.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Noted, tnx but it makes easier to understand the problem and solve it fast.

Comment: It doesn't matter one bit. Stack Overflow *does not* rely on external sites. If someone posts a question with *only* a link to a jsfiddle (or any other external site) it will be closed. This is why they added [snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), to provide a similar preview feature, inside of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your LESS to (please note I've updated the font & content so I didn't have to import glyphs font):

```
ul {
    padding:20px 0 0 0;
    & > li {
            list-style-type: none;
            & > a:not(:last-child):after {
                margin-top:3px;
                content:">";
                font-family:'arial';
                text-align:right;
                font-size: 10px;
                float:right;
            }
        }
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 13px;
    }
}
```

Note that the ">" is at the far right hand side of the output window.
See working example here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/6duxLkc4/

Comment: Took me a while to work out how to use LESS in jsfiddle. Just for reference check out this fiddle with instructions: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/ Note the External Resources references less.min.js (this is the part that's not in the instructions!)

Comment: @TijnSnijders I saw you added a comment and removed it. This confirms that the method does work: https://jsfiddle.net/6duxLkc4/2/